# Maven package issue locally?

Tags: java, maven

I run mvn package and I get this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gs-maven: Could not resolve dependencies for project DD2480-Group-15:gs-maven:jar:0.1.0: Failure to find com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:3.6 in http://download.java.net/maven/2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of java.net2 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

And below is my pom.xml file:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It was working with Travis on Github, but it doesn't work locally?

Comment: Looks like a wrong configuration in your `settings.xml`. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
mvn clean package -U
```

form description this key :

```
Forces a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories
```

Comment: Dmitrii after that i get:Could not resolve dependencies for project DD2480-Group-15:gs-maven:jar:0.1.0: Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:3.6 in java.net2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2)

Comment: try to check your central maven repository setting. Set http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 for example. You try to find dependency in the wrong repo

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to your local Maven repository (`~/.m2/repository/`).
2. Find the `com/fasterxml/jackson` directory within the repository.
3. Manually delete the `jackson` directory.
4. Run the Maven command with the update option to force an update:

```bash
mvn clean install -U
```

Hope, this might work